# Can I restore my contacts on new phone?

Tags: contacts, google-account, restore

I was using Samsung Galaxy S Duos, which was stolen 2 months back. I now have a new Android phone - the Micromax. I thought I lost all my contacts, but somebody insisted that you can restore it using Gmail account even though I never manually performed a backup of my contacts. I remember the day when I took the phone, and it asked me for a Gmail account.

For my profile and I gave the Gmail account and also always "Account sync" option was on in my mobile.

Now my questions are:

1. Can I still get those contacts restored on my new mobile? I have not manually done a backup, just the Gmail account that I set when I got that phone was in sync.
2. If yes, can I get it on Micromax cell also?

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure that your contacts from your old phone were saved as Google contacts. You can do that by going to: http://www.google.com/contacts from any computer and login in with the Google account you used on your old phone.

If your contacts are there - you're in luck. Just add this Google account to your new phone and the contacts will be synced.

Comment: Or just `contacts.google.com` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both of your questions. Once you attempt to sync your phone to gmail, it should ask you if you want to import contact from your Google account. That said, if you exported your contacts from your previous phone, then you will be able to retrieve them on any Android device.

Comment: His previous phone was a Samsung Galaxy. If he backed up to Samsung Account (Cloud) he won't be able to restore to Micromax using Google Account. These are two independent, parallel systems. Also, Auto Backup is enabled by default, so he will definitely be able to restore, unless he intentionally disabled it.